# Stop sharing file with a single user only - OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-office

Is it possible to stop sharing a file with a single user only and keep other links active through OneDrive. I’ve shared an Excel file with around 20 people. I want to stop sharing it with one user but keep the other links active.

Comment: You can remove users the same way you added them.

Comment: In OneDrive, select the file or folder you want to stop sharing. Select Information in the upper-right corner to open the Details pane. Select Manage access. Remove the person that you want to stop sharing.